# Apple App Store Badge Redirects to Shady advertisement on mobile but not desktop

Tags: html, ios, redirect, dns, ghost-blog

I recently published an app to the app store and am trying to put a "Download on the app store" badge on my personal blog.  I first used the badge generator tool at https://tools.applemediaservices.com but noticed when I click through the badge on an iOS device (my iPhone and my brother's iPhone), I am directed to a shady "Spin the Wheel!" or "You've won!" webpage.  When I click through via desktop web browser, the link opens up the App Store just fine! I'm baffled.  I reworked everything from scratch and same behavior persists.

Blog Link: https://keeganleary.com/flutter-app/ (The Badge is just below the web app)

Clicking with thumb on iPhone redirects to pages with goobly-gook addresses like (Don't Follow, I added some ... to hopefully keep anybody from following this link!): `https://4i9...gx8uxvn13l...top/t/fe312738ec36/99fda6ec-568c...1=`

If I long-press and copy link, then paste into browser on iPhone, it opens up the App Store like it should!

Functionality is same on Chrome and Safari, and two different iPhones.

My code

```
<figure>
    <a href="https://apps.apple.com/us/app/super-pace-calculator/id1548388283">
        <img src="https://keeganleary.com/content/images/2021/01/Download_on_the_App_Store_Badge_US-UK_blk_092917.png">
    </a>
    <figcaption></figcaption>
</figure>
```

My best guess is my website or iPhone browser is hacked somehow but I have no idea.  Tried clearing caches as well but same thing happens.

Comment: Works for me on both Chrome (Mac) and Safari (iPhone)

Comment: Thanks.  On iPhone you did a simple tap of the badge icon?

Comment: Yeah, a simple tap.

Comment: Thanks. Still having the issue on my end despite resets and cache clears 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I analyzed your site and found no virus.

I noticed that you are using disqus on your site, I am almost sure that these ads came from the disqus that, unfortunately, inject ads without our permission, generally unwanted or deceptive low quality ads that can even hinder users' navigation.

Take the test, disable DISQUS from your site and see if the ads disappear.

unfortunately I have not found another way to disable these ads if not buying the subscription where you can disable the ads.

Comment: That was it.  Thank you so much.  Disqus disabled.  1 star Yelp review for Disqus.  5 star Yelp review for you.

Comment: test this new solution I just discovered, disable these two options in Settings> Advanced> "Tracking" and "Affiliate links", then let me know if the ads are gone.

Comment: That also fixed the behavior.  In my personal profile settings on the Disqus website there is an "Opt-out" from tracking option as well.  Regardless, the experience was horrible enough that I definitely won't be using Disqus on my site anymore and have recommended to the Theme's creator that it be removed by default, or to better document how it can affect the site's behavior.  Thanks again!

Comment: I did a short write up complete with screen recording on my website so hopefully it helps somebody https://keeganleary.com/disqus-is-evil-trash/